# how to use case_when rather then if_else [Error in my code?]

Tags: r, dplyr, vectorization, tidyverse, case-when

I'm trying to realize why I cannot use `dplyr::case_when` rather than `dplyr::if_else`.
Probably I'm missing something. Let me explain:

I got this operation which works fine:

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    keep = if_else(
      assembly_level != "Complete Genome" | genome_rep != "Full",
      FALSE,
      ifelse(
        version_status == "suppressed",
        FALSE,
        if_else(
          refseq_category %in% c("reference genome", "representative genome"),
          TRUE,
          if_else(
            rpseudo > 0.4,
            FALSE,
            TRUE
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

but, when I try using `case_when` this way

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    keep = case_when(
      assembly_level != "Complete Genome" | genome_rep != "Full" ~ FALSE, 
      version_status == "suppressed" ~ FALSE,
      refseq_category %in% c("reference genome", "representative genome") ~ TRUE, 
      rpseudo > 0.4 ~ FALSE,
      TRUE ~ TRUE
    )
  )
```

I got different results.

I think the problem is just the use of the function.

If you need the data, it is a general public data and may be downloaded here: ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/ASSEMBLY_REPORTS/assembly_summary_refseq.txt

to get:

```
read_tsv("ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/ASSEMBLY_REPORTS/assembly_summary_refseq.txt", 
         comment = "#",
         col_names = c(
           "assembly", "bioproject", "biosample", 
           "wgs_master", "refseq_category", "taxid", 
           "species_taxid", "organism_name", "infraspecific_name", 
           "isolate", "version_status", "assembly_level", 
           "release_type", "genome_rep", "seq_rel_date", 
           "asm_name", "submitter", "gbrs_paired_asm", 
           "paired_asm_comp", "ftp_path", "excluded_from_refseq", "relation_to_type_material"
         )
) %>%
  select(assembly, refseq_category, 
         assembly_level, genome_rep, 
         version_status, release_type) %>%
  mutate(
    rpseudo = runif(nrow(.), 0, 1)
  ) -> df
# it will got some warnings
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please dont' abbreviate `TRUE/FALSE` to `T/F`

Comment: Is just because it is easy to write, I changed it in the code.

Comment: I understand that, but I wouldn't recommend to use that because you can assign `T/F` as object identifier and this can create huge issues if not chekced properly

Comment: Your code is not reproducible `Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'assembly' not found`. Is there any steps you forgot to copy?

Comment: Your column names in your `select()` to not match the names in your `col_names=` when you read the data. This should be giving you an error.

Comment: I don't find `assembly_level` in the data

Comment: I feel that you are using too many nested conditions here, you only have two outcomes so why not just use one `ifelse` statement like this 
`df %>%
  mutate( keep = ifelse(
      assembly_level != "Complete Genome" | genome_rep != "Full" |
        version_status == "suppressed" |rpseudo > 0.4 
      ,FALSE, TRUE  )  )`

Comment: Should have no errors no more

Comment: @Mike I agree but actually the  `refseq_category %in% c("reference genome", "representative genome")` is mandatory up all other conditions. Then the statement should be : `df %>% mutate( keep = ifelse(refseq_category %in% c("reference genome", "representative genome"),TRUE,ifelse(assembly_level != "Complete Genome" | genome_rep != "Full" | version_status == "suppressed" | rpseudo > 0.4 ,FALSE,TRUE)) )`. Anyway I still missing why I cannot do with `case_when`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are `NA`'s in the data.  Store the output from `if_else` in `df1` and the one with `case_when` in `df2`. The only difference between `df1$keep` and `df2$keep` is `df1$keep` has got few `NA`s in them and at those place `case_when` has got some real values. Check

```
table(df1$keep, useNA = "always")
# FALSE   TRUE   <NA> 
#156616  10386     79 

table(df2$keep, useNA = "always")
# FALSE   TRUE   <NA> 
#156647  10434      0
```

and if you do

```
(156647 - 156616) + (10434 - 10386) #It gives exactly
#[1] 79
```

Also if you remove those `NA` values and then check values in `df1` and `df2` they are the same.

```
all(df1$keep[!is.na(df1$keep)] == df2$keep[!is.na(df1$keep)])
#[1] TRUE
```

---

The way `NA` is being handled in `if_else` and `case_when` is different. Consider this simplified example for better understanding.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(a = c(1:3, NA, 4:7), b = c(NA, letters[1:7]))
```

Now let's create some random conditions to test. Using `if_else`

```
df %>%
  mutate(res = if_else(a > 3, "Yes", 
                   if_else(b == "c", "No", 
                           if_else(a > 5, "Maybe", "Done"))))

#   a    b  res
#1  1 <NA> <NA>
#2  2    a Done
#3  3    b Done
#4 NA    c <NA>
#5  4    d  Yes
#6  5    e  Yes
#7  6    f  Yes
#8  7    g  Yes
```

However, with `case_when` you get output as

```
df %>%
   mutate(res = case_when(a > 3 ~ "Yes", 
                          b == "c"~"No", 
                          a > 5 ~ "Maybe", 
                          TRUE ~ "Done"))

#   a    b  res
#1  1 <NA> Done
#2  2    a Done
#3  3    b Done
#4 NA    c   No
#5  4    d  Yes
#6  5    e  Yes
#7  6    f  Yes
#8  7    g  Yes
```

So if you notice in `if_else` if an `NA` is encountered it returns `NA` immediately. However, in `case_when` it treats `NA` as `FALSE` so if `NA` is encountered it goes to next condition until any condition is satisfied or else return value of `TRUE`.

**data**

```
set.seed(1234)
read_tsv("ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/ASSEMBLY_REPORTS/assembly_summary_refseq.txt",
comment = "#",
col_names = c(
       "assembly", "bioproject", "biosample", 
       "wgs_master", "refseq_category", "taxid", 
       "species_taxid", "organism_name", "infraspecific_name", 
       "isolate", "version_status", "assembly_level", 
       "release_type", "genome_rep", "seq_rel_date", 
       "asm_name", "submitter", "gbrs_paired_asm", 
       "paired_asm_comp", "ftp_path", "excluded_from_refseq", "relation_to_type_material"
     )
) %>%
select(assembly, refseq_category, 
      assembly_level, genome_rep, 
     version_status, release_type) %>%
 mutate(
  rpseudo = runif(nrow(.), 0, 1)
 ) -> df
```